# Proving an integral of products of a function is equal to a regular integral.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Given $f \in C([a,b])$, we also define $V= \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n | a\leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \cdots \ x_n \leq b \} .$

Now, I want to solve the following equation:

$$ \int_V \prod_{1\leq j \leq n} f(x_j) dx= \frac{1}{n!}\left( \int_a^b f(t)dt)\right). $$

I have shown this to be true for $n=1$ and $n=2$, and so I thought that perhaps I should use induction to prove the whole equation to be true. However, I wasn't able to figure out how to apply the inductive step to this integral. Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid its just not true. Pick $f=1$ and $b=1$ and $a=-1$, then
$$\int_a^bf(t)\, dt= 2 \mbox{ and } \int_V1dx=(b-a)^n=2^n.$$
Hence 
$$2^n=\frac{2}{n!},$$
which is not true. What you may want to look into is Fubini's Theorem. It yields
$$\int_V\Pi_{j}f(x_j)dx=\Pi_j\int_a^b f(t)\, dt= (\int_a^bf(t)\, dt)^n$$

Comment: Thank you for the suggesting Fubini's theorem, do you perhaps know of any texts or books which further explore the steps required to go from $\int_V\Pi_{j}f(x_j)dx$ to $\Pi_j\int_a^b f(t)$? I'm not familiar with this theorem and searching for it online yield slightly different results than the one above.

Comment: @ Ruben: It depends on how deep you want to go into measure theory. In your setting it may be avoided by only utilising Riemann integrals instead of Lebesque Integrals. Apostol's Book 'Mathematical Analysis' gives you an introduction and what you need should be in Chapter 14.5. Please note that Fubini's Theorem is also in this book but given in a later chapter about Lebesgue Integrals, but as I said before I don't think you actually need it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your notation, it is not a true identity, for $n=2$, $f(x)=x$, $a=0$, $b=1$
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^x xy\,dy   \,dx=\frac1{2!}\int_0^1 x^3\,dx=\frac1{2!4}\neq \frac 1{2!2} = \frac 1{2!}\int_0^1 x\,dx.
$$